# Django - performance practice to assign request.user to variable in view

Tags: python, django

Probably, it is the silliest question here, but I have a view with lots of `request.user` like:

```
def my_view(request):

    some_stuff1 = request.user.param1
    some_staff2 = request.user.param2

    if request.user.param3 > request.user.param4:
        // another stuff with request.user
```

So, the question is, will it be better for performance to make something like

```
user = request.user
```

somewhere in the beginning of view? Where is the tag for stupid questions?

Comment: IMO it's more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)ier and cleaner if you do it like `user = request.user`.

Comment: In terms of performance it would save you a few dict lookups, that's it.

Comment: It is probably more readable with user = request.user, so that's as good a reason as any to do it.